# Does the radula sac in any mollusc serve a purpose other than sheathing the radula?

Tags: evolution, molluscs

According to [Barne Gat Shellfish](https://barnegatshellfish.org/radula_02.htm):

> When not feeding the radula is retracted into this chamber which protects the mouth from the sharp teeth of the radula.

Does the radula sac serve any other purpose?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it does?

Comment: @theforestecologist no particular reason. I just thought if the sac can be protected from the teeth, why only that and not the rest of the mouth?